# Getting a LED to light with a push switch, using a raspberry pi and breadboard

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I am having some problems getting my LED to light properly. I am using a push switch. What is happening is that when I run the code, the LED starts on, and when I press the button, it turns off. However, I want it to start start off and then turn on when I press the button. I felt like this would be an easy fix, but when I try to reverse things, it just ends up staying off and the button doesn't do anything at all. I do not believe that I have any wiring problems, it is most likely just problems with the code, because other programs that I run work ok. This is the code I am using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while False:
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
    while True:
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH) 
except KeyboarrdInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You need to use different GPIO for the button and the LED.  while False does nothing as False is False.  while True repeats the block for ever as you have no mechanism to leave the block.

Answer (score 1):

Take one wire of the switch and connect it to it's own gpio pin set for input. Let's say, 17.

Take the other wire from the switch, and connect it to GND.

Take the LED and connect the anode (+) to gpio 18, and the cathode (-) to GND.

Try this script.

(I do not use python, so this script is not tested, just a guess)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

try:
    while True:
        gp = GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.BOTH, timeout=3000)
        if gp is not None:
            if GPIO.input(17):
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
            else:
                GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH) 
except KeyboarrdInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: updated script after briefly reading up python syntax